# React Native Webview IOS GPU Process Issue

Tags: react-native, webview

I am using [QrCode styling](https://github.com/kozakdenys/qr-code-styling) for my mobile app in React Native. However, this library does not supporting React Native. Therefore, I am using webview to demonstrate qr code which is generated via html code.

Actual problem is: if I use webview, after creating few qr codes, ios gpu process gives error and app crashes. I give ios simulator' s log from xcode below.

```
GPUProcessProxy::gpuProcessExited: reason=IdleExit
WebProcessProxy::gpuProcessExited: reason=IdleExit
(lldb) (lldb) (lldb) (lldb) (lldb) (lldb) (lldb) (lldb)
```

[xcode thread error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cUYu.png)
and my rn code

```
    <WebView
        onContentProcessDidTerminate={() => webViewRef.current.reload()}
        ref={webViewRef}
    startInLoadingState={true}
    scrollEnabled={false}
    shouldRasterizeIOS={true}
    cacheEnabled={false}
    style={styles.qrStyle}
    containerStyle={styles.qrContainerStyle}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    source={{ html: html({ link: qrUrl }), }}       
     />
```

Also, I tried some html to img packages but does not work on mobile.

html({ link: qrUrl }) function returns qr code's html.
you can find source html on [QrStyler](https://github.com/kozakdenys/qr-code-styling#usage)

I need a way the show this qr code correctly, Is there any idea?